# How to implement hanging punctuation in NSTextView?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uitextview, nstextview

[image: hanging punctuation]

I want to implement hanging punctuation in native Cocoa framework, but don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

The system in modern iOS and MacOS that you would have to work with is called [TextKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/textkit).

The latest version of TextKit, TextKit 2, was released last year.  The WWDC session describing TextKit 2 is available from Apple's Developer videos [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10061/).

An important class you will likely have to work with is [NSTextLayoutManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextlayoutmanager).

This is a rich set of functionality but that should give you a starting place.  Before you get too deeply enmeshed in it I would double and triple check that there is not already support for it in the OS.